# Can't set visibility on a SearchView with savedInstanceState

Tags: java, android, android-view

My activity has a menu which includes a SearchView, and I'm setting the SearchView visibility programmatically.  I'm using savedInstanceState to preserve the Visibility value eg between rotations, but this aspect is not working: in the scenario where the SearchView visibility is GONE before rotation, the SearchView icon is showing after rotation.

If I debug and evaluate `mSearchView.getVisibility()` after picking up its value from savedInstanceState, it appears to be correctly set to 8.

There are lines in my code which `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`, but none of them are hit between the value from savedInstanceState being set, and the rotated layout appearing to the user.

**Layout:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!-- "Mark Favorite", should appear as action button if possible -->

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

**Activity (onSaveInstanceState):**

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    switch (mSearchView.getVisibility()){
        case View.VISIBLE:
            outState.putInt("SearchViewVisibility",View.VISIBLE);
        case View.GONE:
            outState.putInt("SearchViewVisibility",View.GONE);
    };
}
```

**Activity (Menu setup):**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    //setup SearchView and callbacks
    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    if(mSavedInstanceState != null){
        switch (mSavedInstanceState.getInt("SearchViewVisibility")){
            case View.VISIBLE:
                mSearchView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            case View.INVISIBLE:
                mSearchView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            case View.GONE:
                mSearchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            SetFragmentAndFilter(query);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            // check whether this change is clearing all text from the search
            if(query.isEmpty()){
                // close the searchView
                mSearchView.post(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        mSearchView.clearFocus();
                    }
                });
                mSearchView.setIconified(true);
            }
            //have the list match the new query text
            SetFragmentAndFilter(query);
            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Would really appreciate any thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [setVisible](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setVisible(boolean)) method to set the visibility of a menu item.

Change your code to

```
// Add this property
MenuItem mSearchMenuItem;

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean("isVisible", mSearchMenuItem.isVisible());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    //setup SearchView and callbacks
    mSearchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    if (mSavedInstanceState != null) {
        boolean isVisible = mSavedInstanceState.getBoolean("isVisible", true);
        mSearchMenuItem.setVisible(isVisible);
    }

    mSearchView = (SearchView) mSearchMenuItem.getActionView();
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            // check whether this change is clearing all text from the search
            if (query.isEmpty()) {
                // close the searchView
                mSearchView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mSearchView.clearFocus();
                    }
                });
                mSearchView.setIconified(true);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! This + changing all my `mSearchView.setVisibility()` lines to `mSearchMenuItem.setVisible()` resolved it.  Thank you.